# the alternative for NCCL on window 10

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

So I am on windows 10 and am using multiple GPUs now in order to run the training of some machine learning model and this model is about GAN algorithm you can check the full code over [here](https://github.com/tkarras/progressive_growing_of_gans) :

Here, I get to the point where there is need to reduce the sum from different GPU devices as following:

```
 if len(devices) > 1:
            with tf.name_scope('SumAcrossGPUs'), tf.device(None):
                for var_idx, grad_shape in enumerate(self._grad_shapes):
                    g = [dev_grads[dev][var_idx][0] for dev in devices]
                    if np.prod(grad_shape):  # nccl does not support zero-sized tensors
                        g = tf.contrib.nccl.all_sum(g)
                    for dev, gg in zip(devices, g):
                        dev_grads[dev][var_idx] = (gg, dev_grads[dev][var_idx][1])
```

Now in this part I get an error regarding NCCL, which I noticed that is not supported on windows it needs linux, therefore I am stuck here...what is the "work around solution" here??..how can I manage to use NCCL on windows or an alternative to the code above..is there any simple way to do that?...thanks in advance.

Note: I have checked out some stackoverflow issues already. However, no answer exist which can solve my problem.

Comment: There is no NCCL for vanilla Windows and no plans to add it. 
Please follow-up on running GPU on WSL2: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl (but it's at an early development phase, so I wouldn't count on it either.)

Answer (score 3):

Try using gloo: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html

and add this at the beginning to your code:

```
import os 
import torch
os.environ['PL_TORCH_DISTRIBUTED_BACKEND'] = 'gloo'
os.environ['NCCL_DEBUG'] = 'INFO'
torch.distributed.init_process_group(backend="gloo")
```

Hope it helps (I did this to make work llama on my windows computer)